# Foundation-icons in rails not working in production-enviroment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, icons, zurb-foundation, production-environment

I can't get the foundation-icons to show in production-enviroment (deployment) while in development it works just fine.
When I start the server in production-mode via nginx and the gem puma, basically the only error I get is this:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/foundation-icons.css")
```

I've tried to add this to config/enviroments/production.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( vendor/foundation.scss )
```

and I precompiled using RAILS_ENV=production

I'm using the latest version of foundation:

```
gem 'foundation-rails', github: 'ahacking/foundation-rails'
```

Using ruby 2.0.0.p353 and Rails 4.0.2.

**Edit:**
Foundation-icons has no real relation to the foundation gem. (I wasn't the guy who implemented it in the application)

**Edit 2:**
Added `config.assets.compile = true` in `config/environments/production.rb` witch removed the error, however the icons are still missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a gem for foundation-icons that works like a charm

https://github.com/zaiste/foundation-icons-sass-rails